# Elasticsearch, reindex deletes data in the target index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch node (`ES1`) in local network.

We had a power outage for few days, and I set up another ES node (`ES2`) in aws-ec2 for the duration.

Now I want to transfer data which are collected in the temporary ES node (in aws) to the original ES node in local network.

Can I use reindex from `ES2` to `ES1` ?

ES1 and ES2 have disjoint data (no documents have same document id)

Would it keep the documents in the ES1's index and add ES2's documents onto ES1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just experimented this. and yes it appears that documents are preserved (when document ids are disjoint)

So you can combine data from ES2 to ES1 without deleting data in ES1 with `reindex`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [Elasticdump](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump) to dump a copy of the data from ES2, then recover it to your local ES1, you can recover to any index in ES1 if there is no mapping conflict.

[Elasticdump](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump)